# Sony SW2: how to work with TunnelService?

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

I've got a widget and I need to execute new `ControlExtension` in SW2 when clicking on the widget.

I catch the click in `onReceive()` in `AppWidgetProvider`. How can I send requests to watch using `TunnelService`?

Answer (score 0):

there is a method in `ControlExtension` class called sendToHostApp:

```
/**
 * Send intent to host application. Adds host application package name and
 * our package name.
 *
 * @param intent The intent to send.
 */
protected void sendToHostApp(final Intent intent)
```

Is this what you are looking for?